# How to compare values on panda series

Tags: python, pandas

I have this error on my code. I would like to know what to do.

My code is:

```
while (g < 6) or (df['close'] > Shoot*0.7):
    if (df['close']> df['close'].iloc[0]+10):
    resete = df['close']* 1/Shoot
    resete = resete -1
    usdt = resete* usdt
```

The error came in this line:

```
if (df['close']> df['close'].iloc[0]+10):
```

Please what can i do ?

Comment: What is the error? Your indentation seems to be off, the line after `if` needs to be indented.

Comment: Show the traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Also add an explanation of what this is supposed to do.